# Sort custom field by post

Tags: custom-field, customization

Ok it is pretty simple. Every post of my blog has a specific country. So i have the custom field country and then, when i write the article i add: japan, argentina, usa, italy etc. to the post. Now in home i like to have a box like that:

Post By Country:

Japan (130 posts)
Usa (104 posts)
Argentina (90 posts)
Italy (46 posts)
Uk (23 post)

etc, etc. Then, be able to click on a contry and have all the post from that country. I'm not so familiar with php queries, can u help me?

Tnx a lot.

Comment: Giorgio, If you want to ask for clarification on an answer you should post a comment on the answer. Please read through the FAQ to familiarize yourself with the way this site works: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq As far as how to have a box in the sidebar that querys the custom fields and then posts links to custom loops, I am sure there is a way to do this but that is beyond my skill set. I know for a fact that it can be done much easier with custom taxonomies however I have never done this and don't know the exact code for you to use.  Maybe someone else will be more help than I was.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a loop that pulls all your post with the custom field key "Country"...

```
<?php
$countryPosts = new WP_Query();
$countryPosts->query('meta_key=country');
?>
<?php while ($countryPosts->have_posts()) : $countryPosts->the_post(); ?>
CONTENT STUFF HERE
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Now to order that you can add `order=ASC` or `order=DESC` so this line reads:

`$countryPosts->query('meta_key=country&order=ASC');`

Here's the loop that will show all the post that have the custom field filled out for a specific country, in this example, Japan:

```
<?php
$countryPosts = new WP_Query();
$countryPosts->query('meta_key=country&meta_value=japan');
?>
<?php while ($countryPosts->have_posts()) : $countryPosts->the_post(); ?>
CONTENT STUFF HERE
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Update:** After re-reading your question I realized I may not fully understand what you are trying to do correctly.  The above code will let you display posts from a specific country but it won't show that "archives" type navigation box.  From the sound of it, you may want to [create](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/introducing-wordpress-3-custom-taxonomies/) a [custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Taxonomies) for countries rather than using a custom field.  This will make it a lot easier to interact with the posts based on the Country.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a custom field, you should add a [custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies). You can query posts by taxonomy then.